# Error parsing HTTP request header only when on server, works fine on local host

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, spring-mvc, tomcat, web-applications

I am trying to get some data and present it as an Excel download. I do this through the following code:

```
      "ajax": {
      url: $('#url').val(),
      type: "POST",
      data: function (d) {
          //("in data function");

                 if( $('#filter0').val() !=''){
                         d.columns[0]['search']['regex'] = true;
                         d.columns[0]['search']['value'] = $('#filter0').val();
                         $('#pageHeaderL2').html("<button class='myButton' style='cursor:default;' type='button' name='" +  $('#filter0').val() + "'>" + $('#filter0').val() + "</button>");
                         //("set default facility");
                 }
                 if( $('#filter1').val() !=''){
                         d.columns[1]['search']['regex'] = true;
                         d.columns[1]['search']['value'] = $('#filter1').val();
                         $('#pageHeaderL5').html("<button class='myButton' style='cursor:default;' type='button' name='" +  $('#filter0').val() + ":" + $('#filter1').val() + "'>" + $('#filter0').val() + ":" + $('#filter1').val()  + "</button>");
                         //("set default module");
                 }


                 if($('#searchValueIn').val() != "")// depending on if you module search or global search the search string is stored in a different location, this saves the search val in a string
                    var searchVal = $('#searchValueIn').val();
                 else
                    var searchVal = $('#searchValueLocal').val();

         var dd = $.extend({}, d, {
          "originalSearchValue": searchVal
          //"useDefaultFacility": $('#filter0').val() !='' ? true : false,
          //"useDefaultModule": $('#filter1').val() !='' ? true : false,
                    });

         currentTableMeta = dd;

         return dd;
      },
      dataSrc: function(json) {
             for ( var i=0, ien=json.data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                 json.data[i][0] = '<a href="/message/'+json.data[i][0]+'>View message</a>';
                 }

          if($('#searchValueIn').val() != "")
              var searchVal = $('#searchValueIn').val();
          else
              var searchVal = $('#searchValueLocal').val();

         var hrefExcel= $('#excelurl').val() +'?searchValue='+ searchVal +'&' +  $.param(currentTableMeta) ;
         // debugger;

          if($('#tableExcel').length < 1) {
              $('#partTable_filter').css({left: 10, position:'absolute'});
              $('#partTable_filter').prepend($('<a id="tableExcel" href="' + hrefExcel + '" class="btn" style="float:right; margin-left: 5px;"><i class="icon-table"></i> Excel</a>'));
                /* $('#tableExcel').on("click",function(e) {
                  //var abc = $(currentTableMeta).serialize();
                  var abc = $.param(currentTableMeta);
                  debugger;                });  */
                 // alert("in the IF");
            $('#partTable_processing').before("<br /><br />");
          }else{
            $("#tableExcel").attr('href',hrefExcel);
            //alert("in the else");   
            alert("After the Click");
          }
          tableSortRowObj = $("#sortRowState");


          //("this current sort:" + tableSortRowObj);

          updateFilterFields(json);
          //("to isnert:" + newRowOfFilters);


          return json.data;
      }
  },
```

This completely works when if I run it on my local tomcat server using Chrome or firefox, but once I deploy the code to my test server it doesn't work using chrome or IE. Firefox can download the excel but it doesn't download with a file extension. This is the error I get from the server:

```
Aug 16, 2016 12:16:20 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor process
INFO: Error parsing HTTP request header
```

On my local host I get the following error from trying to run using IE.

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Comment: Is there a reverse proxy (apache, nginx...) in your test environment ?

Comment: @benjamin.d Any thing else you cant think of?